# Identifying tests left in wrong package after refactoring

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm in the process of cleaning up a badly thought out package structure. This involves a lot of moving of classes around between packages.

The eclipse refactoring tool does not automatically move any corresponding unit tests to the new package, so I must remember to do this manually. I generally forget to do this as I am lazy, stupid and forgetful.

I'm considering knocking something together to identify tests that look to be in the wrong package, but would prefer to use something off the shelf.

Do any such tools exist?

Comment: run tests and see what fails? ;)

Comment: This would be a good tool, hopefully it exists, but I wouldn't bet on it. Moving test classes along with actual classes is not a refactoring, technically speaking. Since there are no standard ways of tying up a class to a test, the tool would have to do some (educated) guessing.

Comment: @acdcjunior yes it couldn't be bullet proof. In my case the tests follow the common <classname>Test pattern so it should easy to infer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MoreUnit](http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/) moves test classes automatically when the corresponding classes are moved.

Comment: I had MoreUnit installed a few years ago but uninstalled it pretty quickly for reasons I now forget. Just given it another try and it seems to work nicely without getting in the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your unit tests follow the standard naming convention `<class>Test`, then you could write up a classpath scanner that first identifies all your unit tests (ones that have the name finishing on 'Test', and ones that have the `@Test` annotation at least once) and then for each you can get its name `"com.foo.<class>Test"`, remove the test, you end up with `"com.foo.<class>"` and then you can check if the test itself has a instance variable that is of the `"com.foo.<class>"` type. If not, you can fire a warning or something.

So, assuming you have a class like that

```
package com.foo.Bar

@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bar {
   public int doSomething(){
    //...
    return 1337;
   }
}
```

and a test:

```
package com.foo.fooo.BarTest

public class BarTest {

  private com.foo.Bar bar;  

  @Before
  public void setup(){
     bar = new Bar();
  }

  @Test
  public void testSomething(){
  //testing and stuff
  }
}
```

Then, you can find that the BarTest class is a unit test class (cause it has the `@Test` annotation and also has a name that ends on Test). You can see the instance variables bar has, and get their fully qualified. You would get a `com.foo.Bar`, which would be wrong, since your test is in package `com.foo.fooo`, so you would fire a warning that your test class is in a different package than the class it tests. This would work for 90% of the test classes I am writing, of course, this is a very ideal situation, in a real test, you might have more than one type of instance variables, and then you would have to infer which one is the one tested from the name of your unit test and expect at least one of its instance variables to be of the correct class type.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer seems to be that no such tool exists I've gone ahead and put something together myself - it was natural fit for an additional feature for a tool I maintain.

In case it's of use to anyone else it's available in the 1.1-SNAPSHOT of

https://github.com/hcoles/highwheel

It's currently just a simple test that infers the name of the class under test assuming a naming convention of

```
Test<Foo>
```

or

```
<Foo>Test
```

is being followed. If that class does not exist it looks to see if another class of the same name exists in a different package.